# Area the triangle with vertex in the the vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ $u,v,w$.

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Let $u=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$, $v=(v_1,v_2,v_3)$, $w=(w_1,w_2,w_3)$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Find the area the triangle with vertex in the $u,v,w$ in terms of the entries of vectors $u,v,w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magnitude of the cross product of two vectors is the area of the parallelogram spanned by two vectors, so the area of the triangle with vertices $u$, $v$, and $w$ is $$\frac{1}{2} \|(u-w)\times (v-w)\|.$$

I.e., translate everything to the origin by subtracting $w$ from $u$ and $v$, then the area of the triangle with vertices $u-w$, $v-w$ and the origin is half of the area of the parallelogram spanned by $u-w$ and $v-w$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Use the cross product. We have

$$S=\frac{1}{2}|(\vec{v}-\vec{u})\times(\vec{w}-\vec{u})|=\frac{1}{2}|\vec{v}\times\vec{w}+\vec{u}\times\vec{v}+\vec{w}\times\vec{u}|.$$

The area $S$ is invariant under permutations of the vertices $\vec{u},\vec{v},\vec{w}$.